# how to insert many similar records in mysql at a time using phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wildcards

we know that we can insert multiple records at a time using this query:

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE1` (`First`,`Last`) VALUES ('name1','surname1'),
('name2','surname2'),
('name3','surname3'),
('name4','surname4');
```

but what if we want to add 1000 similar records as above (name*,surname*) do we have to write down all the records or we can use something like wildcard? or is there any other solution using mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this script:

```
set @a=0;
INSERT INTO `TABLE1` (`First`,`Last`) SELECT
CONCAT('Name',(@a:=@a+1)),CONCAT('Surname',@a)
FROM `information_schema`.`SESSION_VARIABLES` LIMIT 1000;
```

, where `information_schema.SESSION_VARIABLES` is any big table with at least 1000 rows.

Comment: This should have been asked on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW binary_view AS SELECT 0 n UNION SELECT 1;

SELECT CONCAT('name',s),CONCAT('surname',s) FROM (
SELECT
    b0.n * POW(2,0) +
    b1.n * POW(2,1) +
    b2.n * POW(2,2) +
    b3.n * POW(2,3) +
    b4.n * POW(2,4) +
    b5.n * POW(2,5) +
    b6.n * POW(2,6) +
    b7.n * POW(2,7) +
    b8.n * POW(2,8) +
    b9.n * POW(2,9) s
FROM
    binary_view b0,
    binary_view b1,
    binary_view b2,
    binary_view b3,
    binary_view b4,
    binary_view b5,
    binary_view b6,
    binary_view b7,
    binary_view b8,
    binary_view b9
HAVING s BETWEEN 1 AND 1000 ) t;
```

Comment: Could you possibly and a short explanation on what your code does?